# @interface for 'UIAlertView"

Tags: xcode4, interface, xcode4.2, uialertview

When I'm trying to compile my code; this code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lost!"
    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You were hit! Try again!"]
    delegate:nil
    cancelButttonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

is having this error:
`No Visible @interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the sector`

Comment: Please don't use bold / italic for normal text and code. We have formatting standards. Also, please don't revert valid edits.

Comment: @Polynomial: I added back his revert and formatted it nicer, since your revert removed the code that contained the error.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3312&p=20213

You have an extra t in cancelButttonTitle. Should be cancelButtonTitle.

Comment: Thanks soo much!! Hahah i didn't even see the extra 't'

Comment: Yeah, you can stare at stuff like that for hours.

Comment: Can you mark this as the approved answer? In general you should mark answers on this site as approved, or people don't really like helping you with future requests.